# Torchvision Beta features not found (torchvision.transforms)

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I'm following this [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html) on fine tuning a pytorch object detection model. The first code in the 'Putting everything together' section is problematic for me:

```
from torchvision.transforms import v2 as T


def get_transform(train):
    transforms = []
    if train:
       transforms.append(T.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5))
    transforms.append(T.ToDtype(torch.float, scale=True))
    transforms.append(T.ToPureTensor())
    return T.Compose(transforms)
```

I've checked that i have torchvision 0.15.2 and pytorch 2.0.1 so the requested beta features should be present. But I get two errors: first, ToDtype has no argument 'scale', and that ToPureTensor does not exist. When checking my files, they are clearly different from the [docs](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/transforms/v2/_type_conversion.html#ToPureTensor).

Simply copying the relevant functions won't work because then it says I don't have `tv_tensors` in `from torchvision import tv_tensors` in the linked docs. Downgrading torchvision to 0.15.0 won't change anything. What can I do? I'm on windows (no cuda, using cpu), with conda if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with the tutorial and noticed the following instruction at the beginning:

> This tutorial works only with torchvision version >=0.16 or nightly. If you’re using torchvision<=0.15, please follow this tutorial instead.
> https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/blob/d686b662932a380a58b7683425faa00c06bcf502/intermediate_source/torchvision_tutorial.rst

My environment was running torchvision 0.15.2. When I used the code from the above link instead of the original documentation, it worked successfully.

Additionally, be cautious when using utility codes. For older versions, opt for specific versions rather than the main one, such as the link below:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/vision/v0.15.2/references/detection/engine.py